# Video Clip Color Spaces

Tags: video, color, color-management

I'm trying to understand how color spaces for video clips in Blender work, currently the video clip I'm importing looks quite a bit off. I've set the render view transform to Standard and the video clip and render display device is set to sRGB.
The video was shot on an iPhone, I've attached screenshots of the video details and the clip as viewed in QuickTime vs Blender. I'm guessing the video is not encoded as sRGB but not sure how to correctly configure it.

Video details –
[image: video details]

QuickTime preview –
[image: video QuickTime preview]

Blender viewport –
[image: video Blender viewport]

Comment: I think the issue might be a bug with importing `heic` videos (on Mac). I converted the video to `h.264` and the colors look correct.